# Engine stopping as if no fuel most of the times

Tags: engine, choke

I have a Pulsar 150 2005 model and it has done 225000 kilometers.

It had no problems what so ever as of now until the recent showers. It starts runs for sometime and then turns off as it there is no fuel once I turn on the choke it becomes normal. I know it is not a wise option to drive with the choke turned on. Could you all suggest me the reason for the fault.

Note: I got the carburetor cleaned with a local mechanic, however the problem still persists. The mechanic suggested me to replace the carburetor.

Comment: Did you ride it constantly before the problem started or was the bike still for a while? It could be some persistent dirt in the carburetor that didn't get cleaned the first time or some air leak that is causing more air to be aspired to the mixture.